# fetching the data when using prepared statements with mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

This is the standard code I found online that etching the data when using prepared statements with mysqli:

```
$sql = "SELECT Title, CopyrightYear FROM Books WHERE ID=?";

if ($statement = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql)) {

    mysqli_stmt_bindm($statement, 'i', $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement); //Question 1 
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $title, $year);

    while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)) {  //Question 2 
        echo $title . '-' . $year . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

I have some questions:

1. why we don't store the result of mysqli_stmt_execute? we can use something like:

`$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);` then we can retrieve each record from the result set?

2. Since we have already executed the query, what does `mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)` mean? don't we have executed the $statement already, shouldn't it be like this : mysqli_stmt_fetch($result)?

Comment: `mysqli_stmt_bindm()` ?????

Comment: `prepare` sends the query to the database for compilation and optimisation. It does not actually run the query Obviously as it has a `?` parameter that needs binding before the query is actually complete

Comment: `execute` runs the query, but does NOT return the resultset that is generated by the query execution

Comment: The `fetch` gets one row from the resultset each time you call it

Comment: If you lookup the mysqli_stmt_execute, you'll see it returns a boolean, not a result set [mysqli_stmt_execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php).

Comment: While youare developing Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why we don't store the result of `mysqli_stmt_execute`? we can use something like: `$result = mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);` then we can retrieve each record from the result set?

That's because `mysqli_stmt_execute()` function **only** executes a query that has been prepared using the `mysqli_prepare()` function. When executed any parameter markers which exist will automatically be replaced with the appropriate data. It **doesn't return any result set**, rather it just returns the status of the execute query i.e. either `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

> Since we have already executed the query, what does `mysqli_stmt_fetch($statement)` mean? don't we have executed the $statement already, shouldn't it be like this : `mysqli_stmt_fetch($result)`?

Again, since `mysqli_stmt_fetch()` function just executes the prepared statement and doesn't return any result set, you need to bind the variables to the prepared statement for storing the result. And from [**the doc**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php),

*When `mysqli_stmt_fetch()` is called to fetch data, the MySQL client/server protocol places the data for the bound columns into the specified variables var1, ....*

Comment: Thank you for your answer.so is $statement a result recource? And is mysqli_stmt_execute($statement) executing the query( the reaultset has been generated) or it is just exexuting the statement(male sure the statement compiles, no resultset has been generated yet)?

Comment: @whoisit `$statement` is a [MySQLi statement object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php), and it's not something you can directly loop through after the prepared statement(like you would do with [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)). And as I said in the answer, `mysqli_stmt_execute()` doesn't return any result set, it just executes the query that has been prepared using the `mysqli_prepare()` function and replace any parameter markers,if exists, with the appropriate data.

Answer (score 2):

The execute function doesn't return a result, but [mysqli_stmt_get_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) does. Then you can fetch one row at a time from the result resource. This usage might make more sense to you:

```
if ($statement = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql)) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'i', $id);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
    $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($statement);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $row['title'] . '-' . $row['year'] . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

One reason no result set is not returned from the execute function is that some SQL statements (like INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, etc.) have no result set. So the execute function only returns a boolean to indicate whether the statement ran successfully or not.

Comment: 。Thank you for your answer.so is $statement a result recource? And is mysqli_stmt_execute($statement) executing the query( the reaultset has been generated) or it is just exexuting the statement(male sure the statement compiles, no resultset has been generated yet)?

Comment: @whoisit, $statement is a [mysqli_stmt](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-stmt.php) resource. As I said, some statements return no result set.